# VS Debug Config vs dll statically linked VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I downloaded a library called nanolib here:
https://de.nanotec.com/produkte/9985-nanolib

It comes with a VS 2019 solution as example. The example preconfigures only release config.
The example runs fine in release, even though the output displays exceptions.
When adding debug config, the example results in exceptions in xmemory (0x00000000005) and crashes.
The exceptions are access violations.

The vendor told me that this is not an issue in their code, because the library got statically linked to release VC++ 17 one simply can't use VS Debug config.

I don't want to include a ticking time bomb in my setup.
I am distrustful on this and would like to have the opinions of some captain, since I dont have the necessary knowledge.

Comment: The vendor's info is accurate.  They built their library with the release flavor of the runtime libraries, they can't be mixed with the debug flavor.  In effect you'll have two copies of the runtime in your program, very destabilizing due to their global state.  Use Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > "Runtime Library" = /MT.  You'll lose some diagnostic power but can still debug your own code.

Comment: if I switch to /MT I have to add linking to ucrtd.lib, but then I get:
libucrt.lib(invalid_parameter.obj) : error LNK2005: _invalid_parameter already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll